# "Language missing or invalid"

Tags: 9

I am using Drupal Version 9.5.5 and Forum core module.
After enabling the module and creating a forum container, forum, and topics, the module creates a page at /forum/ with a table list of the forums.

Chrome Wave shows an error in the *Last post* column: *Language missing or invalid*. It is coming from the variable {{ forum.last_reply }}

This is an example of the HTML markup.

```html
<a title="View user profile." href="/user/1" lang="" about="/user/1" 
typeof="schema:Person" property="schema:name" datatype="" 
class="username">drupal</a>
```

I was able to fix it with JavaScript.

```js
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('.forum').length > 0) {
      $(".submitted a").attr("lang", "en");
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is reported as a bug in the module https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3353837